# How can I load a php file without showing it? (/page.php -> /page)

Tags: php

I want to run localhost/page?test=1 but since I use php I have to create a folder called "page" and then an index.php file inside it. Even if I do that it's not the same, I'll have to call localhost/page/?test=1 and not localhost/page?test=1

I really didn't know what to google so this is the perfectly way to describe my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `htaccess` to remove the file extension from the URL --> to map `index` to `index.php` in the URL

So the URL becomes

`localhost/page/index?test=1` instead of `localhost/page/index.php?test=1`

Read how to do It and more about `.htaccess` [here](https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/)